# error while integrating java to salesforce

Tags: integration, java

1. setup for java environment and eclipse working fine
2. Navigate to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc in your browser and
   download the WSC pre-built .jar file that matches the API version of Salesforce you’re using.
3. WSC uses the Rhino JavaScript framework, so if you don’t have this installed, navigate to
   [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download_Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download%5fRhino) and download the latest
   .zip file. Un-archive the .zip file and move the folder to a location you’ll remember.
4. Generating Java Stub Files (WSDL-based APIs)

   develop-->api-->downloaded wsdl file.

Trying in command prompt:

But getting in an error

> C:>java - classpath F:\11\pathToJAR\wsc-23.jar
>   com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc F:\11\pathToWsdl\enterprise.wsdl?
>   F:\11\enterprise_stub.jar Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: û Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: û
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: GÇô.  Program will exit.

Comment: please avoid using the salesforce-crm tag and try to find tags specific for your question.

Comment: Agree. This is not a SFDC question.

Answer (score 0):

I also have done this and I didn't require any javascript framwork.

Just follow the instruction given on blow link

[Salesforce for java](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_for_Google_App_Engine_Setup_Guide_Java)

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question, it is simply a link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer